# How can I reset font zoom in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, zooming

I am working in Visual Studio Code. I was copying something when I hit the wrong shortcut key (not sure which one) and the editor window zoomed out (to about half the size). See image below.

[image]

Note that this is not the View > appearance > zoom setting at work as the whole program/window is not zoomed in or out. Either way, I selected to reset to default zoom and it did not fix the issue. Rather, ONLY the editor window is zoomed out.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `editor.action.fontZoomOut` command was run. Bring up the command palette (`ctrl+shift+p`) and type "font zoom reset" to find the command to revert.